# Matching multiple patterns with ls

Tags: shell, ls, patterns

I'd like to get a list of fail logs in the current directory for use in an outside script, the logs are determined with the pattern FAIL in the filename, so I've been using a FAIL* to feed my script files to open and process. However, for each FAIL file there are two types, a compressed file and an uncompressed one. I just want to open the uncompressed file.

Is it possible to chain find FAIL* but not if *.gz/bz2/whatever exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can test against the presence of a regex for those extensions:

```
for file in *FAIL*; do [[ ! $file =~ .(bz2|gz) ]] && printf "%s\n" "$file"; done
```

Insert obligatory warning about [not parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)...

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `find` command you can omit the files that end in the extension `.gz` like so:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Oct 15 22:42 FAIL
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Oct 15 22:42 FAIL.gz

$ find . -name "*FAIL*" ! -name "*.gz"
./FAIL
```

You can also filter `ls` output like so:

```
$ ls *FAIL* | grep -v '.gz'
FAIL
```

But it's generally advisable to not parse `ls` output since it's not structured so that it's conducive to do so.